# UK tourist visa - duration of stay

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, long-term

My mother was given a UK tourist visa for 2 years with a duration of stay of 180 days. It is a C-type multiple-entry visa.

Is 180 days the total stay she can take or is it the duration of stay per visit?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum 180 days per visit. So in 2 years she can stay for more than 180 days in multiple visits.

All she needs to ensure is that she doesn’t try to live in the U.K. for extended periods just by going out for a few days to come back for next 180.

As long as the visits remain visits she will not have any trouble even if the total number of days in multiple visits exceed 180.

Comment: I am thinking of making her stay approx 9/12 months with a break at 4.5 months. She is widow Nd 100% dependent on me but not financially. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: @Gaurav Puri The typical advice is to spend at least the same amount of time in your home country as in the UK. 9 months at a time may flag a concern at Immigration IMHO

Comment: Rough rule of thumb - 180 days in, 180 days out.

Comment: Staying for 180 days, leaving for a few days and then trying to come back for another 180 will definitely attract attention, and not be guaranteed to be approved.

Answer (score 0):

I secured a visit visa for my Dad Late in September 2023 and the visa was approved for 180 days and flight booked immediately for 25th November for him to travel which he is currently in the UK.
The 180 days is always multiple and he must returned according to the law as stated on the Visa Vignette. Any breach he will have issues with the Home office whenever he wants to renew.
Even if the visa is for 2 years as long as it is a visit visa, the applicants must be travelling within 180 days tranches until the visa expires and must not overstay in any of the 180 days permit given. That is my view

Comment: I downvoted the answer as the poster gives no information about the source of their assertions.

Comment: All UK visit visas have a duration of 180 days as standard (with very rare exceptions). It is not a given that repeated 180 day stays will be granted on arrival at the border, even with a longer-term Visitor visa. To get a long-term Visitor visa, the applicant needs to show a reason. IMHO any long-term visa holder would be wise to ensure their pattern of travel during the validity of the visa is in line with the stated reason. Eg ‘to visit my son while he is at university’ doesn’t necessarily translate to repeated 180 day duration visits.